# css precedence: overriding only one of height and width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write some CSS that sets a default height and width for an image, which may be overridden by other CSS in any given case. So for example:

stylesheet:

```
.imgsize_60x30 { width: 60px; height: 30px; }
.foo img { width: 80px; height: 40px; }
```

html:

```
<html>
<img id="i1" class="imgsize_60x30" src="myimage.png">
<div class="foo">
  <img id="i2" class="imgsize_60x30" src="myimage.png">
</div>
</html>
```

So i1 displays at 60 x 30, and i2 displays at 80 x 40. Cool. That works fine.

But then I run into this case:

```
.bar img { width: 100px; }

<div class="bar">
    <img id="i3" class="imgsize_60x30" src="myimage.png">
</div>
```

So now I get the width from ".bar img", i.e. 100, but the height from ".imgsize_60x30", i.e. 30, and the image comes out distorted. When a class specifies the width, I want the browser to go ahead and calculate the height. But when I get neither a width nor a height, I want my defaults to apply.

Of course if I didn't put the class="imgsize_60x30" on the img tag it would work fine. But the catch is that the page is built dynamically based on many lines of code and data from a database, so figuring out what CSS might apply to any given tag would require me to pretty much re-invent all the logic CSS uses to apply styles -- I'd have to parse all our generated HTML, find all class references, parse the CSS, apply precedence rules, etc. So what I was trying to do was just always put certain classes on certain images to give them these default sizes.

Is there any way in CSS to say, "If you don't have either a height or a width from somewhere else, use this height and width. If you do have a height and width from somewhere else, use what you've got" ?

The program is in VB.NET, so if there was a way in the code to say, "Hey, what's the height of this element?", that would be better still. But to the best of my knowledge, there's no way to ask from within VB code what CSS styles will be applied to an element, other than inline styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but if you put `height: auto` inside `.bar img` - the image will keep it's ratio:

```
.bar img { 
    width: 100px; height: auto;
}
```

Here is a working snippet:

```css
.imgsize_60x30 { width: 60px; height: 30px; }
.foo img { width: 80px; height: 40px; }
.bar img { width: 100px; height: auto;}
.bar1 img { width: 100px;}
```

```html
<img id="i1" class="imgsize_60x30" src="https://dummyimage.com/60x30/s7e/ffe">
<div class="foo">
  <img id="i2" class="imgsize_60x30" src="https://dummyimage.com/60x30/s7e/ffe">
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <img id="i3" class="imgsize_60x30" src="https://dummyimage.com/60x30/s7e/ffe">
</div>

<div class="bar1">
  no auto height:<br />
    <img id="i3" class="imgsize_60x30" src="https://dummyimage.com/60x30/s7e/ffe">
</div>
```

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Ooh, that works. I may have to change a bunch of styles to add the "auto", but a solution that is a pain but that works is usually better than a solution that is easy but doesn't work. :-)

Comment: The big issue is that you can't really ask (using css) if an element already got some other css-value by some other selector, so we must use the `auto` here.

Comment: "Can't ask" Yeah, that was the problem I was wrestling with.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I don't know any better solution (and you will have to go over all your `* img {...}` lines in your css), but your final solution should work :)

Comment: Yes, I actually just scanned all the CSS files on this project for "img" (why do we have so many CSS files ... ?) and there were about 20 rules that needed to be changed, wasn't all that horrifying. And half of them were for one screen, but whatever. Might be some other places setting a height and/or width for a particular image not using "img" anywhere in the rule, just using the ID of that image or whatever. I think I'll deal with those as they show up in testing. Thanks.